# My approval workflow on SharePoint Online keeps failing

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, flow, approval-process, power-automate

Can someone please suggest how to stop the time out issue?

[image: Here is an image of my flow, and the areas that are failing.]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot, the issue lies on the parallel part. The Start and wait for approval action simply does not get started. And I am not sure about the logic behind the Do until part. More information about the Flow logic will be helpful.

You may need to double check with the start and wait for approval and check where goes wrong.